# Can you run 32-bit python on Enthought Canopy for Mac?

Tags: python, macos, pygame, canopy

I use Enthought Canopy on my Mac (MacOS 10.13.2), and I really want to use pygame, but since pygame is a 32-bit module, it doesn't run on Canopy on Mac. (I'm new to all this by the way) I was wondering if I could change my Canopy's python to a 32-bit version.

Comment: Perhaps the easiest solution would be to run a Linux virtual machine on your mac and run the necessary 32-bit applications in there? I know macs also have a way to run individual applications in 32-bit mode, but that might be more difficult for this.

Answer (score 0):

> Canopy 1.5.2 is the last version available for 32-bit Mac OS X. Canopy 1.5.5 is the last version available for 32-bit Linux.

https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204754434-Last-32-bit-Canopy-Versions-Mac-OS-X-Canopy-1-5-2-and-Linux-Canopy-1-5-5-